# How can I get a medium-size goat for my gnome?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, creature-size, mount, animals

I am looking to get a goat as a permanent mount.
Nothing fancy, I want to ride her, use it as mule, and be able to do basic tricks with her.
I don't plan to use it in combat. If it matters, I am looking for a female to drink her milk and bake cheese.
I am fine with a look-alike animal that we can adapt to be flavorful.

[image: Warcraft goat]

My character is a [gnome](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127339/is-there-a-way-for-a-gnome-to-grab-the-favored-class-options-from-an-aasimar-ins) buffer bard. I will buff as far as I can from the battle.
I am fine with investing one feat if needed, but I don't want to dip.

What are my options?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Tame a Dire Goat

Yes. In fact, Pathfinder already includes a medium-sized Goat. Behold the mighty Dire Goat! You will need a bit of [Handle Animal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/handle-animal):

> To rear an animal means to raise a wild creature from infancy so that it becomes domesticated. A handler can rear as many as three creatures of the same kind at once.
>   **A successfully domesticated animal can be taught tricks at the same time it’s being raised, or it can be taught as a domesticated animal later.**

*(emphasis mine)*

If you dont have a lot of rank into [Handle Animal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/handle-animal), maybe someone else can tame the Dire Goat for you.

[image: Dire Goat]

> This giant goat stands as tall as a halfling at the shoulder. Its fur is whitish–brown and its horns are yellowish–brown.

[d20pfsrd Dire Goat entry](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/herd-animals/goat/dire-goat-tohc/)

Answer (score 10):

## Buy a Ram

A Ram is male sheep. Sheep and goats are closely related: both are in the subfamily [Caprinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caprinae).
A female is called an ewe. They are Medium sized. You can buy one for 25gp and 50gp if combat trained. You can find them under the *Ridable Creature* section of the page [Ride](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/ride).

[image: ewe]

> A formidable pair of heavy horns curls from the forehead of this sturdy, brown-and-white-furred ram.

[d20pfsrd Ram entry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/herd-animals/ram)

Comment: Noting that the Ram entry specifically supports using it for other caprines: "You can create stats for smaller, similar animals (such as goats) by applying the young creature template to a ram".

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Alas, but the young creature template reduces size by 1.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer It does, but then you can add the Giant template to make a *big* goat! (Though in practice, it'd make more sense just to leave out the Young template; they mostly cancel out anyway.)

Answer (score 7):

## Reskin

There are two basic approaches to this sort of question. One is to find rules for goats, and then look for a way to make them ride-able, and aloisdg has given three options along those lines.

The other way is to find something that's already ride-able, with roughly the right stats, and make it a goat. For instance:

Take one [Riding Dog](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/canines/dog/riding-dog/).

Change "dog" to "goat". Change "bite" to "gore". This is a minor downgrade since the damage changes from B/S/P to P, but since you're not planning on using this for combat, it doesn't matter. No need to change the Trip special attack. Optionally, move one skill point and the Skill Focus feat from Perception to Climb.

Voila! You now have a Medium-sized riding goat.

[image: Image: a dog dressed up in a goat costume]

In the end, the stats are pretty similar to the [ram](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/herd-animals/ram) that aloisdg suggested. However, reskinning is sometimes easier to sell to a GM. There's less need to worry about balance issues, especially in this case where the reskin is based on a "standard issue" mount for small PCs, and it reduces the number of rulebooks required (something that, IME, GMs often appreciate!)

Answer (score 5):

## Choose a Goat as familiar

### Part 1. Get a Goat

Wait. Bards doesn't have familiars!

#### Part 1a. Use an archetype

[Duettist Bard](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/duettist-bard-archetype/) does. Be a duettist.

#### Part 1b. Use feat(s)

If your DM lets you use the 3.5 feat [Obtain Familiar](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Obtain+familiar+feat+Complete+Arcane) (Complete Arcane, p. 81), go for it. The other solution cost two feats! (thanks @KRyan)

Pick [Skill Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/skill-focus-final/), to unlock the mighty [Eldritch Heritage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eldritch-heritage/).
Skill Focus can be used for your favorite Knowledge skill. As a Bard, I am sure you check the CHA 13 condition. With Eldritch Heritage, you select the Arcane Bloodline which grants a familiar.

OK, now you can have a familiar. Let's continue.

In the [list of familiars](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar), you will find the [goat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/herd-animals/goat).

Problem is, this goat is Small. A mount suited for you is at least one size category larger than you.

### Part 2. Get a Medium-size Goat.

1. Take the feat [Undersized Mount](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/undersized-mount-combat). The goat is still Small, but you can ride it.
2. Use the [Mauler archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar/familiar-archetypes/mauler-familiar-archetype/). Include it with the familiar!
3. Buy a permanent [Animal Growth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animal-growth) on it. Cost 13020gp. (4x13x10gp +12500gp)

Wait. Why can't I buy a goat directly? Yes you can, but it won't scale and no mauler for you.
[image: baby goat]

> A small and timid herd animal.

[d20pfsrd Goat entry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/herd-animals/goat)

Comment: Two feats for a familiar is patently absurd—it might be worth noting the far-more-reasonable Obtain Familiar feat for 3.5, found in *Complete Arcane*.

Comment: Nevertheless, you are right two feat is not cheap. This feat from 3.5 is far better. I will add it.

Answer (score 1):

## Pet a Deer, Ringhorn

Since you are fine with a look-alike animal. I have another solution for you. Paizo has medium-sized goatlike deer. The Ringhorn can be use as Animal Companion. As far as I know, there is no way for a [bard to get an Animal Companion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/55133/11129).

[Animal Ally](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/animal-ally) is a feat from Pathfinder Player Companion: Faiths & Philosophies who grants an animal companion:

> Your respect for nature is so great that you can form a deep and lasting friendship with an animal.
>
> **Prerequisites**: Nature Soul, character level 4th, must not have an animal companion or mount that advances as an animal companion.
>
> **Benefit**: You gain an animal companion as if you were a druid of your character level –3 from the following list: badger, bird, camel, cat (small), dire rat, dog, horse, pony, snake (viper), or wolf. If you later gain an animal companion through another source (such as the Animal domain, divine bond, hunter’s bond, mount, or nature bond class features), the effective druid level granted by this feat stacks with that granted by other sources.

As a DM, I would close my eyes on the last [prerequisite](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/3geej1/can_bards_have_animal_companions/cty3h8r). Check with yours. With [Nature Soul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/nature-soul/), it is two feats for an animal.

In another hand, 3.5 has the [Wild Cohort](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56756/does-the-animal-provided-by-the-wild-cohort-feat-count-as-an-animal-companion) feat as alternative.

[image: jose parodi bestiary ringhorn]

> The horns of this goatlike deer grow up and curve around into a pair of massive, spiraling rings atop its head.

[d20pfsrd Deer, Ringhorn entry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/deer-ringhorn/)

Comment: How do they eat?!

Comment: @MichaelRichardson with their mouth.

Comment: Well yeah.   But most grazing is not going to be within reach, with the horns blocking access.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson woosh

Comment: *magic* also, tall grass and narrow bushes are things